# On an identity for the matrix logarithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional positive definite matrix and let $\log X$ denote its principal matrix logarithm. It is well-known that the following identity holds
$$
\mathrm{tr}\log X = \log \det X.
$$
Now, let $Y$ be another $n$-dimensional positive definite matrix and consider the following quantity
$$
f(X,Y):=\mathrm{tr}(Y\log X).
$$

> **My question.** Is it possible to rewrite this function in the form
>   $$
> f(X,Y)=\log g(X,Y),
> $$
>   for some scalar function $g(X,Y)$ of $X$ and $Y$ (excluding the trivial case $g=\exp f$)? In case of negative answer, do there exist some class of matrices $Y$ for which this is possible (excluding the trivial case $Y=I$)?

Comment: I guess you don't just want the answer $g = e^f$?

Comment: @user399601: Yes, I wonder whether there exist some "less trivial" form, as in the case $Y=I$.